# Google play console trial end before subscription

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have the app on play market. When I launch it, it offers a free one-month period. After it automatically starts a paid subscription.
Can I make it so that after the trial period ends, the subscription doesn't start? So that the user signs up for the trial first, nothing happens after it ends. My app will offer to subscribe on its own.

I tried to find information in the documentation, but I can't find the right information.

Comment: There is no such option AFAIK, it's a marketing trick to get money from the user.

Comment: @DerekK what if i create a basic plan with only a trial and a second plan with only a subscription?

Comment: I doubt it's possible to create a base plan with trial only, but you can give it a try.